# I can't count the number of tries in this game in pythin

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I got a task to make a game of guesses using python. In my assignment, I was told to count the number of tries. But I can't make it work. Any suggestion would be appreciated. (note: the list is for nothing...I was just messing with the code and trying things.)
`

```
# import random
# a=random.randint(1,30)
a = 23
Dict1 = ["Hello there! How are you?", 0,
         "Guess a number Between 1 to 50",
         "Your number is too high",
         "Your Number is too low",
         "Make Your Number A Bit Higher",
         "Make Your Number a Bit Lower",
         "Congratulations You Have guessed the right number :)"
         ]
print(Dict1[0])
name = input("What is your Name?\n=")
# print("hi!,{}, Wanna Play a game?".format(name))
print(Dict1[2])

while 1:
    inp = float(input("="))
    if inp > 50:
        print(Dict1[3])
        continue
    elif inp < 1:
        print(Dict1[4])
        continue
    elif inp < a:
        print(Dict1[5])
        continue
    elif inp > a:
        print(Dict1[6])
        continue
    elif inp == a:
        print(Dict1[7])
    q = input("Do You Want to Go again? Y or N\n=")
    if q.capitalize() == "Y":
        print('You have', 5 - 4, "tries left")
        print(Dict1[2])
        continue
    elif q.capitalize() == "N":
        break
    else:
        break
op = inp
while 1:
    x = 4
    if -137247284234 <= inp <= 25377642:
        x = x + 1
        print('You have', 5 - x, "tries left")
        if x == 5:
            break
if x == 5:
    print("Game Over")
```

`

Comment: Why are all your strings in a dictionary, except for a few?  Is this for language adjustment?  Also, your indentation doesn't look right in this code.

Comment: @RufusVS :) I was messing up and just trying things... Because I am a beginner...

Comment: `Dict1 ` is a list ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Safayat. I reverted your last edits, since the answer should not be part of the question. SO is a "question and answer" site. The question is the thing above, and the answers are separate posts below. If one of the answers solved your problem, you do not need to repeat that in the question. If it did not solve your problem and you have a better solution yourself, it is allowed to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @wovano Thanks for your assistance... I will consider your advise in my future questions...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about it would be to set up a variable to track attempts outside the while loop between `a` and `Dict1`

```
a = 23
attempts = 1
Dict1 = [...]
```

Then each time they make an attempt, increment in the while loop:

```
    if inp > 50:
        print(Dict1[3])
        attempts += 1
        continue
    elif inp < 1:
        print(Dict1[4])
        attempts += 1
        continue
    elif inp < a:
        print(Dict1[5])
        attempts += 1
        continue
    elif inp > a:
        print(Dict1[6])
        attempts += 1
        continue
```

**EDIT:**

Looking more carefully at your code, it seems like you want a countdown. So you could change it to

```
attempts = 5
```

and in the while loop

```
while 1:
    ...
    if q.capitalize() == "Y":
        attempts -= 1
        print('You have', attempts, "tries left")
        print(Dict1[2])
        continue
```